# How to compare two array of objects in javascript and update the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

i am having two array of objects like this

```
let array1 = [{
    id:1,
    colorCode:2
}]

let array2 = [{
    id:1,
    value:3
}]
```

Here what i want to achieve is . I need to compare this two arrays and their id's are same.I need to change the `colorCode` value depends upon the `value`. Pls help me to achieve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: But what are you comparing? What about the colorcode do you want to change? is the value always going to be 3? if so i don´t really see the point of the question.

Comment: the value is dynamic . For eg: if value = 5 . The colorCode needs to changed according to a particular value range.

value 1 to 5 => colorCode: 1

value 5 to 10 => colorCode: 2

like this.

Answer (score 2):

U can use mapping

```js
var array1 = [{ id:1, colorCode:2},{id:2, colorCode:2}];
let array2 = [{ id:1, value:3},{id:2, value:4}];
var arr=[];
array1.map(id =>       
   arr.push({id:id.id,colorCode: array2.find(o => o.id === id.id).value})
 );
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function using `_.flow()`. The function concats the arrays, `_.groupBy()` the key (`id`), and then `_.map()` the groups, and `_.merge()` each group:

```js
const { flow, concat, groupBy, map, merge } = _;

const combineBy = key => flow(
  concat,
  arr => groupBy(arr, key),
  groups => map(groups, g => merge({}, ...g))
)

const array1 = [{ id:1, colorCode:2},{id:2, colorCode:2}];
const array2 = [{ id:1, value:3},{id:2, value:4}];

const combineById = combineBy('id');

const result = combineById(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

The same idea is even simpler with lodash/fp. Just replace `_.merge()` with `_.mergeAll()`:

```js
const { flow, concat, groupBy, map, mergeAll } = _;

const combineBy = key => flow(concat, groupBy(key), map(mergeAll))

const array1 = [{ id:1, colorCode:2},{id:2, colorCode:2}];
const array2 = [{ id:1, value:3},{id:2, value:4}];

const combineById = combineBy('id');

const result = combineById(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```